# No resource found for abc_test_vector.xml

Tags: android, android-support-library

I recently updated with Support Library 24.2.1 and I rebuild my App with it..
But the App crashed on Startup..
Logcat shows error like -

```
No resource found for abc_test_vector.xml
```

I've searched in AppCompat 24.2.1 & found the file in res/drawable/ then why this error?

Even the Sample App didn't work -

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your surrounding code that is trying to access this resource ?

Comment: There's nothing that's accessing this :)

Comment: Oh, this is a resource in the Support Library ? What are you using from the library? I'd either try removing the library calls, or lowering your version of the library...

Comment: As I read other posts, I foind may be its Navigation drawer.. I'll post code

Comment: @jesses.co.tt updated wid code

Comment: add the full (relevant) logcat too please

Comment: Your NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is sitting outside of the onCreate() method...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt previously, it worked fine

Comment: No, it didn't, you must be mistaken. Unless it was wrapped inside of a function or was a static field, that's impossible.

Comment: The Hello World app also crashed!

Comment: which app is that? a google sample? is it using the same version of the library? i would investigate if this is a known issue - your safest bet might just be to downgrade your version

Comment: why did you delete your code ?

Comment: A simple Material design app..

Comment: that doesnt help... answer all of my questions

Comment: I was gonna show that sample app code :)

Comment: @jesses.co.tt chk code sample

Comment: Please add the full LogCat

Comment: Well this wasn't a Bug in Support Lib and not even in my App but AIDE had...
Updated now, works fine...
Thanks for ur Help :)